# gnuplot: xdata time and boxes

Tags: gnuplot

I have some temperature data in a text file, and I would like to represent it in a 'boxed' plot, showing the temperature of each day like an histogram.

```
23 10 2012 12.3
28 10 2012 14.1
30 11 2012 30.4
...
```

I'm triying to represent it with a simiple gnuplot script like this:

```
set terminal png enhanced font font_file size size_x, size_y tiny
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d %m %Y"
set format x "%d"
set boxwidth 0.9 relative
plot u 1:4 w boxes
```

I would like to leave blank the days where no data is available, but gnuplot gives these days the value of the last day a data was available. For example, in the data file I wrote before, gnuplot would give a 12.3 to the 23th of october, but I would like leave this gap without any bar.

Is there a way to get this? I have discarted an histogram representation because I've read that it is not compatible with time data.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I take it that you mean that gnuplot would give `12.3` for the **24th** of October -- It seems to me that it *should* give 12.3 for the 23rd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is the line `set boxwidth 0.9 relative`.  Relative says that you're trying to fill 90% of the space between adjacent boxes.  You probably want to set an absolute boxwidth.  If you change your script to `set boxwidth 0.9 absolute`, then you'll see vertical lines.  This is because when using time data, the x-axis unit is actually *seconds*, so your box is only ~1 second wide when your x-scale is multiple days.  So, to get each box to be the width of a single day you would use

```
set boxwidth 3600*24
```

Here's the complete script:

```
set term png enhanced
set output 'foo.png'
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d %m %Y"
set format x "%d"
set boxwidth 3600*24
plot 'test.dat' u 1:4 w boxes
```

and the output:

[image]